# I can't review still notified?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, notifications, top-bar

I completed a number of [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) and the following message is displayed.

```
 Thank you for reviewing 20 suggested edits today; come back in 11 hours
 to continue reviewing.
```

However, the top bar still notifies me about the queues.

[image]

When I click on it it shows me the above message. So why does it need to be shown continuously? It is somewhat annoying.

Is there any way I can disable/remove it?

Comment: Yes, this should be fixed.